# Why does SSL_pending return 0 after SSL_read reads 1,400 bytes?

Tags: c++, networking, openssl

```
while(1)
{
    read_blocked_on_write=0;

    const int buff_len = 1024;
    char buff[buff_len];

    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, buff, buff_len);

    int ssl_err = SSL_get_error(ssl, iResult);
    if(ssl_err == SSL_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        if(offset + iResult > recvbuflen - 1)
        {
            FD_ZERO(&fdread);
            FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
            MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("ERROR"), TEXT("Not enough memory!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy(recvbuf + offset, buff, iResult);
        offset += iResult;
        if(SSL_pending(ssl))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            bFinish = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(ssl_err == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)
    {
        bFinish = true;
        break;
    }
    else if(ssl_err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(ssl_err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
    {
        /* We get a WANT_WRITE if we're
        trying to rehandshake and we block on
        a write during that rehandshake.

        We need to wait on the socket to be 
        writeable but reinitiate the read
        when it is */
        read_blocked_on_write=1;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        FD_ZERO(&fdread);
        FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("ERROR"), TEXT("SSL problem!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no ssl expert but it's likely because there is nothing to read.  You are reading and moving a buffer (which takes milliseconds at most) and then terminating if there is nothing more to read at that instant.  Meanwhile you are dealing with the much slower network speeds and decryption at the lower layer.  It's not at all improbable that there is nothing to be returned at that moment.

Why have that check there at all?  Wouldn't alternatively opening the socket as non-blocking be the way to go if you are trying to multiplex or whatever?

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding a select() the else statement of the SSL_pending(ssl). It worked, but upon the last receipt, it waits until the timeout value expires. Is there any better way to solve it?

Comment: @Saleh Hamadeh - That confirms the problem but if I understand what you did it isn't a good fix - you are just widening the time frame with a timeout.  Why use SSL_pending at all if you are willing to block?  Just loop back to the read and block there.  When there is no more data SSL_read should return 0 and it looks as if you have the checks already coded.  The entire SSL_pending condition looks unnecessary for what you want to accomplish.